# Calculate object property value with another property

Tags: javascript, function, object, this, calculation

I am defining an object where I want to calculate one of it's properties with another of it's properties.

```
// first the calculation function
const calculateArea = (height, width) => {
   return height * width
}

// then the object itself...
const myObj = {
   height: 20,
   width: 10,
   area: calculateArea(this.height, this.width)
}
```

I thought I could use `this.height` and `this.width` to access properties within the object I was defining, but I get

> Cannot read 'height' of undefined

Where am I going wrong, and what's the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Comment: It needs to be called after the object is created, you can't reference the object properties while it's still being defined.

Comment: `const myObj = {
   height: 20,
   width: 10,
   area: function(){
    return this.height * this.width
  }
}`

Comment: When the assignment operation takes the outside context.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are trying to reference to your object with `this`, while it doesn't exist. The `this` you reference may be `undefined` (as in your case), which then results in a "cannot read X property of undefined" error.

However the `this` might be bound to another object in the context depending on the situation. In that case you wouldn't get this error and whatever the value corresponds to the bound object's will be returned as `this`.

Trying to fetch a value from the retrieved `this` object may result in 2 cases, both of which are not the thing you want.

- The retrieved `this` has a `width` and a `height` property, so that your function will get these values and calculate the result accordingly. But these values will not be the ones that you passed in your object.
- The retrieved `this` doesn't have a `width` or `height` property, so that your function will get `undefined` as it's parameters and will throw an error accordingly.

There are many ways you can solve this issue. Here is my proposition:

The main issue here is that the value for `area` is calculated eagerly while you are constructing your object. Freezing that calculation and triggering it after the object is created will calculate the correct value within your object.

```
// first the calculation function
const calculateArea = (height, width) => {
   return height * width
}

// then the object itself...
const myObj = {
    height: 20,
    width: 10,
    // init, is a function that uses bounded context's width, height
    init: function() {
        this.area = calculateArea(this.height, this.width);
        delete this.init; // We don't want init in our result object
        return this;
    }
}.init();
```

Now when we call init() of our object, we will have our `this` pointing to the correct object. It will calculate the area with `this.width` and `this.height`. It will also delete the `init()` function from the result object and return the object as in the form you wanted.

We just halted the calculation for a step to have our `this` to point to correct context and then continued.

Comment: I was just looking for a solution like this, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myObj(height, width) {
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
  this.area = calculateArea(height, width);
}

let obj = new myObj(20, 10);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.